# Text following two paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, distort

How can I get my text to follow the path of both the top and bottom lines in adobe illustrator?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the text. (Can be live text, no need to create outlines)

Choose `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp...`

Tick `Preview`

Then select `Bulge` from the drop down menu.

Move the top, `Bend` slider to the left until you are happy. Negative values cause the distortion to work in the opposite direction -- so a reverse bulge.

[image]